# Upgrade RHEL from 7.3 to 7.4: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot

Tags: awt, redhat, java, ibm-jdk

We just upgraded a server from `RHEL v7.3` to `v7.4`.

This simple program works in RHEL v7.3 and fails in v7.4

```
public class TestJava {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false);
    TextLayout layout = new TextLayout("\ude00", font, frc);
    layout.getCaretShapes(0);
    System.out.println(layout);
  }
}
```

The exception in RHEL 7.4 is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:75)
    at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
    at sun.font.Font2D.getFontMetrics(Font2D.java:415)
    at java.awt.Font.defaultLineMetrics(Font.java:2176)
    at java.awt.Font.getLineMetrics(Font.java:2283)
    at java.awt.font.TextLayout.fastInit(TextLayout.java:598)
    at java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:393)
```

Te result on RHEL v7.3 is:

```
sun.font.StandardTextSource@7ba4f24f[start:0, len:1, cstart:0, clen:1, chars:"de00", level:0, flags:0, font:java.awt.Font[family=SansSerif,name=SansSerif,style=plain,size=12], frc:java.awt.font.FontRenderContext@c14b833b, cm:sun.font.CoreMetrics@412ae196]
```

The update of `RHEL v7.4` includes an update of `openjdk` from `1.8.0.131` to `1.8.0.141` but this does not seems to be related to the version of `openjdk`, as the problem is the same with the `IBM JDK` coming with `WebSphere v9.0` (`v1.8.0 SR4 FP6`). With the same version of the `IBM JDK` on a `RHEL v7.3` and `RHEL v7.4` server, the program works in RH 7.3 and fails in RH 7.4 the same way as with `openjdk`

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We finally found it !
RHEL v7.4 (upgraded from v7.3 or fresh install) comes with package `stix-fonts`.
When this package is installed, the default font changed from `Utopia`to `STIX`
So, java now default fonts are mapped to `STIX`, including the`sans-serif`font family
For whatever reason, the `STIX` fonts does not seem to play well with java (`openjdk`+ `IBM JDK`) and cause exceptions and bad calculated artefacts positionning when using `java.awt`, which is the case with `JasperReports`
We ended creating a file name `/etc/fonts/local.conf` with this in order to force back `Utopia` as the default font, used by java..

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>serif</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>dialog</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>dialoginput</family>
    <prefer><family>Utopia</family></prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

**[EDITED 2018-10-22]**
It seems the bug is fixed in JDK 1.8.192: https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8188030

**[EDITED 2019-06-28]**
There is now a fix to work around the problem included in IBM JDK v8.05.37
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IJ16655

Answer (score 7):

#### Environment RHEL 7.4

We are not able to use font sans serif after the upgrade with OpenJDK or IBM JDK.

New Exception using fonts libraries in openjdk 1.8.0.141-2 .
Resolution
The issue is fixed in java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64 . RHSA-2017:2998 - Security Advisory
Workaround

It is observed that in some scenarios installing dejavu-serif-fonts fixes the problem.

#### yum install dejavu-serif-fonts

Answer (score 4):

if you only install any other font like "dejavu-serif-fonts" the problem will be solved. Or you do the workaroundwith the "local.conf" file. RedHat has listet the problem as a bug in 7.4 and is searching for a real solution and dependencies: have a look here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1479563

Answer (score 0):

If someone is having problems running an application on a clean Linux server instance, run the command fc-list and verify if it has multiple fonts and from different folders, in my case, I had some extra fonts in the path /usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/, I removed everything on the folder, and the problem was solved.